# Git checkout fail

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a project I want to bring into Git.
I have my local `git config` complete, verified I can SSH in, and have a branch "`main`" setup on GitHub.
I substituted "`xyz`" for my actual GitHub branch.

The "`git checkout`" command does not appear to be creating a local branch, and no error message is issued.

## `git remote -v`

```
svi     git@github.com:rboudrie/XYZ.git (fetch)
svi     git@github.com:rboudrie/XYZ.git (push)
```

## `git branch -a`

```
remotes/xyz/main
```

## `git checkout -b newbranch`

```
Switched to a new branch 'newbranch'
```

## git branch -a

```
remotes/xyz/main
```

I am attempting to create a local branch, and am expecting the branch to show up in "`git branch -a`" (or just git branch) when done.
I used the "`-a`" on `git branch` to prove I am successfully connecting to my repo on github.com.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you are only handling remote branches... when you run the first "git branch -a" the local main branch should have appeared before the remote one... weird.

try seeing current branch with
`git branch --show-current`

Comment: show current worked - and after that, git branch -a started to work as expected.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use the [obsolete `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), but rather [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).

Second, when you clone your repository, your remote should be named by default "`origin`", not "`svi`"

Try and clone again, to confirm this would work:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:rboudrie/XYZ.git
cd XYZ
git remote -v
git switch -c newBranch
git branch -avv
```